# How to plot a scatter plot over a map separated by divisions?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, geopandas

I want to plot a scatter plot over a map separated by divisions. So far I have tried the following.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

fPath = 'shape/bgd_adm_bbs_20201113_SHP/bgd_admbnda_adm2_bbs_20201113.shp'
bgd = gpd.read_file(fPath)
ax = bgd.plot(figsize=(15,15),column='ADM1_EN', legend=True)
```

**bgd_admbnda_adm2_bbs_20201113.shp** has been found in [github](https://github.com/Shisir/Chemistry/tree/main/shape). It produces this [figure](https://github.com/Shisir/Chemistry/blob/main/download.png).

`Here, there are 8 divisions 'Barishal', 'Chattogram', 'Dhaka', 'Khulna', 'Rajshahi', 'Rangpur', 'Sylhet', 'Mymensingh'.` For every division, there are some **numeric values**(not latitude, longitude values). E.g. for **Dhaka division** [73.13 77.64 74.32 82.48 84.21 88.23 89.90]. For your convenience, I have attached the files in [github](https://github.com/Shisir/Chemistry/blob/main/health.xlsx).
Now, I split the values based on value range. E.g. i) 70-80: [73.13 77.64 74.32], ii) 80-90: [82.48 84.21 88.23 89.90]. Now, I want to draw a scatter plot of two categories of values on any places of Dhaka division with **two colors** such as [this image](https://github.com/Shisir/Chemistry/blob/main/download_LI.jpg). I have attached another **expected output image** for your reference [image: Expected output].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple as plotting data on same axis

- have data of healthcare facilities,  then get GIS data for these facilities
- get map GEOJSON and plot on axis
- scatter data on same axis, using healthcare facility type as color

```
import requests, io
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get some data of healthcare facilities
searchendpoint = "https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations"
# get all healthcare facilities in Herefordshire
dfhc = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(requests
                             .get(searchendpoint, params={"PostCode":f"HR{i}","Status":"Active"})
                             .json()["Organisations"]) 
           for i in range(1,10)]).reset_index(drop=True)

# get geo data for postcodes
dfgeo = (pd.json_normalize(requests.post("http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes", 
               json={"postcodes":dfhc.PostCode.unique().tolist()[0:100]}).json()["result"])
         .rename(columns={"result.postcode":"PostCode","result.longitude":"lng","result.latitude":"lat"})
         .loc[:,["PostCode","lat","lng"]]
        )

dfdata = dfhc.merge(dfgeo, on="PostCode", how="inner")
# going to use as color, so make if categorical so can get codes
dfdata["PrimaryRoleId"] = pd.Categorical(dfdata["PrimaryRoleId"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[14,6])

# get map of regions
df = gpd.read_file(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://martinjc.github.io/UK-GeoJSON/json/eng/msoa_by_lad/topo_E06000019.json").text))
df.plot(ax=ax)
# scatter data on top of region map
ax.scatter(x=dfdata["lng"],y=dfdata["lat"], s=50, c=dfdata["PrimaryRoleId"].cat.codes)
```

#### Using same data set

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

df = gpd.read_file("bgd_admbnda_adm2_bbs_20201113.shp")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[8,8])
df.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
# some data that can be plotted on centroid
df["val"] = np.random.randint(1,100,len(df))

# use a discrete 
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', 5)
# scatter data based on co-ords of centroid
sc = ax.scatter(x=df.centroid.x, y=df.centroid.y, s=50, c=df["val"], cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(sc)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to plot a scatter plot based on numerical values on latitude, longitude values. Can you help me to plot as I expected? It would be very much helpful for me if you draw that using my data.

Comment: `ax.scatter(x=dfdata["lng"],y=dfdata["lat"],` that's scattering based on longitude and latitude

Comment: I have updated to use dataset you note.   Same thing, scatter on top of base created by geopandas